# Time series LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a central repository for IoT device logs. So as the logs arrive they have a timestamp. The problem I want to solve is, over a given time span, the same device might send multiple logs regarding its interaction with a specific catalyst. I want to consider that set of logs as a single event and not 5 disparate logs. I want to count the number of interactions. and not the number of logs.

Data Set

```
public class Data
{
    public Guid DeviceId {get; set;}
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Direction { get; set;}
}

Data d1 = new Data();// imagine it's populated
Data d2 = new Data();// imagine it's populated
```

I am looking for a LINQ query that would yield something along the lines of

```
If ((d1.DeviceId == d2.DeviceId )  && (d1.Id == d2.Id) && (d1.Direction == d2.Direction) && (d1.StartTime - d2.StartTime < 15 minutes ))
```

If i know that the same IoT device is interacting with the same Id (catalyst) and the Direction is the same, and all of those logs occur within a 15 minute time span, It can be presumed that they correspond to the same catalyst event.

I do not control the log creation so ... no i cannot update the data to include "something" that would indicate the relationship.

Data per request... nothing fancy. I am sure most people suspect that I have 30+ properties and I only provide the one impacted by the calculation, but this is a simple set of possibilities

```
class SampleData
{
    public List<Data> GetSampleData()
    {
        Guid device1 = Guid.NewGuid();

        List<Data> dataList = new List<Data>();

        Data  data1 = new Data();
        data1.DeviceId = device1;
        data1.Id = 555;
        data1.Direction = 1; 
        data1.StartTime = new DateTime(2010, 8, 18, 16, 32, 0);
        data1.EndDateTime = new DateTime(2010, 8, 18, 16, 32, 30);
        dataList.Add(data1);

        //so this data point should be excluded in the final result
        Data data2 = new Data();
        data1.DeviceId = device1;
        data1.Id = 555;
        data1.Direction = 1;
        data1.StartTime = new DateTime(2010, 8, 18, 16, 32, 32);
        data1.EndDateTime = new DateTime(2010, 8, 18, 16, 33, 30);
        dataList.Add(data2);

        //Should be included because ID is different
        Data data3 = new Data();
        data1.DeviceId = device1;
        data1.Id = 600;
        data1.Direction = 1;
        data1.StartTime = new DateTime(2010, 8, 18, 16, 32, 2);
        data1.EndDateTime = new DateTime(2010, 8, 18, 16, 32, 35);
        dataList.Add(data3);

        //exclude due to time
        Data data4 = new Data();
        data1.DeviceId = device1;
        data1.Id = 600;
        data1.Direction = 1;
        data1.StartTime = new DateTime(2010, 8, 18, 16, 32, 37);
        data1.EndDateTime = new DateTime(2010, 8, 18, 16, 33, 40);
        dataList.Add(data4);

        //include because time > 15 minutes 
        Data data5 = new Data();
        data1.DeviceId = device1;
        data1.Id = 600;
        data1.Direction = 1;
        data1.StartTime = new DateTime(2010, 8, 18, 16, 58, 42);
        data1.EndDateTime = new DateTime(2010, 8, 18, 16, 58, 50);
        dataList.Add(data5);

        return dataList;
    }
```

Comment: naturally group the data via the deviceId and the Id seems the easy part to me. But grouping by "15 minutes interval" seems a bit more tricky. Do you want to create overlapping groups of 15 min set of logs ? or disjoint groups ?

Comment: Looks like your second code block may contain an error. Did you mean to put `d1.Direction == d2.Direction & d1.StartTime...`?

Comment: @STL I think this is more pseudo code than actual C#, as I understand the question, but let's have OP confirm that.

Comment: LINQ maybe too complex here. What is with a simple method for the job?

Comment: @ user6537157 performance is the reason I was thinking of using LINQ

Comment: It depends if you want to group by natural quarter hours (from 00 to 15, 15 to 30, 30 to 45, 45 to 00) or something more complex.

How would you deal for example with the following set: 19:58, 19:59, 20:02, 20:08, 20:12, 20:15, 20:17, 20:20?

Comment: I was thinking the first log encountered would start the mapping. For any log for a specific deviceId, for the next 15 minutes, if there are additional logs where Id and direction match, only the first record counts. So @Pinx0, given your data set, 19:58 would be log one and I would ignore 19:59, 20:02, 20:08, 20:12.  It would be very odd in my Eco-sphere to get a log from the same Id and direction 15 minutes out. However in your use case 20:15 would again be log one

Comment: LINQ isn't generally more performant, especially LINQ to Objects. It is more about succinct expressions of complicated algorithms. Typically `for` loops will be faster.

Comment: @NetMage Noted and my mistake.I looked at several SO posts that capture your opinion

Comment: Can you provide some sample data with interaction IDs?

Comment: What's the actual question? "How can I [What]"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be more complex than I hoped for.

I used a custom LINQ extension method I have called `ScanPair` which is a variation of my `Scan` method, which is an version of the APL scan operator (which is like `Aggregate`, but returns the intermediate results). `ScanPair` returns the intermediate results of the operation along with each original value. I think I need to think about how to make all of these more general purpose, as the pattern is used by a bunch of other extension methods I have for grouping by various conditions (e.g. sequential, runs, while test is true or false).

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    public static IEnumerable<(TKey Key, T Value)> ScanPair<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, TKey> seedFn, Func<(TKey Key, T Value), T, TKey> combineFn) {
        using (var srce = src.GetEnumerator()) {
            if (srce.MoveNext()) {
                var seed = (seedFn(srce.Current), srce.Current);

                while (srce.MoveNext()) {
                    yield return seed;
                    seed = (combineFn(seed, srce.Current), srce.Current);
                }
                yield return seed;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you can use a tuple as an intermediate result to track the initial timestamp and the group number, and increment to the next (timestamp, group number) when the interval goes over 15 minutes. If you first group by the interaction, and then count the less than 15-minute groups per interaction, you get the answer:

```
var ans = interactionLogs.GroupBy(il => new { il.DeviceId, il.Id, il.Direction })
            .Select(ilg => new {
                ilg.Key,
                Count = ilg.OrderBy(il => il.Timestamp)
                           .ScanPair(il => (firstTimestamp: il.Timestamp, groupNum: 1), (kvp, cur) => (cur.Timestamp - kvp.Key.firstTimestamp).TotalMinutes <= 15 ? kvp.Key : (cur.Timestamp, kvp.Key.groupNum + 1))
                           .GroupBy(ilkvp => ilkvp.Key.groupNum, ilkvp => ilkvp.Value)
                           .Count()
            });
```

Here is a portion of a sample of intermediate results from `ScanPair` - the actual result is a `ValueTuple` with two fields, where the `Key` is the intermediate result (which is the `ValueTuple` of `firstTimestamp`,`groupNum`) and `Value` is the corresponding source (log) item. Using the function seeded version puts the first source item into the  seed function to begin the process.

```
Key_firstTimestamp  Key_groupNum    Timestamp
7:58 PM                 1           7:58 PM
7:58 PM                 1           8:08 PM
7:58 PM                 1           8:12 PM
8:15 PM                 2           8:15 PM
8:15 PM                 2           8:20 PM
```

Comment: I am updating to 4.7 to validate this solution and will mark as accepted upon verification... I also need to chew on it to fully understand.

Comment: @CKIsLearning Yeah, I'm afraid it turned out to be more complex than I hoped. If I figure out a better way to generalize `ScanPair` + `ValueTuple` usage, that would probably help.

Comment: @CKIsLearning I added some intermediate results to show what `ScanPair` is doing.

Comment: validated as correctly solving my problem. Note that it required me to update to 4.7 to utilize this solution

Comment: @CKIsLearning I like to use the latest features, but this could be implemented for earlier versions of .Net pretty easily.